# Which features are missing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

which features you would like to have in Ruby on Rails, or maybe which features you find incomplete or bugy?

Answer (score 7):

It's honestly a pretty full-featured framework. After using it professionally for two years, I have never come across anything Rails couldn't handle. In fact, quite the contrary, I'm constantly finding more and more amazing features I wasn't previously aware of.

Plus with the concepts of gems and plugins, the sky is the limit.

The more you use it, the more you'll love it.

Answer (score 2):

Some things are easier done in pure SQL than ActiveRecord, and some are just impossible without SQL. This breaks the abstraction somewhat.

Comment: Agreed. Although with "find_by_sql", there's still no lack.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's more of a fallback. There's also the `meta_where` gem, which fixes this to some extent, but still.

Comment: Rails 3 made a huge leap with arel. Better eager loading of polymorphic associations would make things easier; also kinda-fixed by `meta_where`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the creation of Engines, modularity & reusability made a huge leap which is great.

I'm wondering whether we'll need another abstraction layer for rich js interfaces. To be a more constructive, I'd personally appreciate to organize my js file the same way I organize my helpers.

@RocketR remark is totally right, as well as tybro0103 conclusion :)

Comment: For rich js there are js MVC frameworks like sproutcore or backbone.js

Comment: @Slawosz: I know that and use Sproutcore a bit but it's still a mess to organize js files properly in MVC frameworks like Rails or Symfony

Comment: Rails 3.1 is about to fix that with the "asset pipeline": http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/5/22/rails-3-1-release-candidate

Comment: @tybro0103: I don't agree, it's just a new name for public/javascripts + useful auto compression

Comment: @apneadiving JS files become first-class citizens... that says it all